# Can't figure out how Maxwell equation about divergence holds for Electric field of a very long cylinder

Tags: electricity, electric-fields, maxwell-equations

So, this is a formula for electric field of an infinitely (or very long) cylinder.

$$\mathbf{E}= \frac{\lambda}{2\pi \varepsilon _{0}r}\mathbf{\hat{r}}$$

And this is the divergence law of **E** field from Maxwell's equations:
$\triangledown \mathbf{E} =\frac{\rho }{\varepsilon _{0}}$
Can't see how this Maxwell equation holds for the cylindrical **E** field written above.
Maybe there's some way to write it with Dirac Delta or something?

Comment: Welcome to stack! Do you know the meaning of the first Maxwell's equation you wrote down?

Comment: This is not a cylinder, but a linear charge density, unless you start specifying conditions on $||r||$, then it is the field outside the cylinder.

Comment: yes that is a field outside the cylinder with linear charge density, I know that but why does it matter, I want to know, why does Maxwell equation not work for that case.

Comment: @Tera I think I know, what makes you ask that?

Comment: @archilkitiashvili Because I do not quite get where your problem is. What makes you think Maxwell's equation would not work here. Could you elaborate on that and explain your understanding so far?

Comment: @Tera I just applied divergence rule to the equation written above and could not get the correct answer, so my problem is where am I mistaken, why can't I take div(E) and get the answer in accordance to Maxwell's equation.

Comment: try using the integral form of Gauss' law instead of the differential forn given

Comment: @bemjanim But why, should not this one also work, or am I missing something

Comment: @archilkitiashvili *"I just applied divergence rule to the equation [...]"* How did you apply it? How did the result fail you?

Comment: And to anticipate a possible answer to the above questions: what tricks did you try to resolve the indeterminancy? Are you asking for a better trick?

Comment: it's just easier to use for discontinuous distributions

Comment: @dmckee I used Del operator for cylindrical coordinates and got 0. My thought is that linear charge density must be reformulated somehow, maybe using Dirac Delta function, but that's exactly my question how to do it.

Comment: *Where* did you get zero (hint: not in all space)? Where should the charge be for that field? What is the result you get where the charge is? And how do you go about fixing *that* problem?

Comment: @archilkitiashvili The electric field of cylinder with a charge inside is calculated from Gauss's Law, so I do not think Maxwell's equation does not work here. As stated above it would be helpful to see your calculations to be able to tell you were you went wrong.

Comment: @Tera my calculation is take E field written above and calculate divergence of that using Del operator with cylindrical coordinates, as simple as that. Nothing more, but I end up with 0.

Comment: @archiI kitiashvili I do not see why you would get 0 and as long as you do not show your whole calculation so far I am afraid we can not help.

Comment: @archilkitiashvili You *do not* end up with zero where the charge is. You really don't. You get the indeterminate form $0/0$.

Comment: @dmckee Well, you just "corrected" my mistake with another mistake. The point is you should end up with charge density divided by vacuum permittivity, according to Maxwell's law. Nothing else.